# RDS Aurora AppSync Error : 400 Bad Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am fairly new to aws.

I am trying to create a simple app using Aurora and AppSync. So far, I have been able to create aurora database, connected to it using MySQL workbench, created the tables that I need.

I have also made the AppSync APIs. And done the resolver (connected the resolver to the RDS Aurora DB).

Here is the problem I am facing, when I try to run queries from the AppSync Queries Tab, it gives me the following error and message:

```
"errorType": "400 Bad Request",
"message": "RDSHttp:{\"message\":\"HttpEndPoint is not enabled for 
arn:aws:rds:us***:cluster:***\"}" (I replaced some details with ***)
```

I have made my Aurora accessible to the public, and I have tried to add a few incoming rules to the security group (i.e. allow all).

However, this error still persists. I have spent a few days on it and will appreciate any help I can get to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS AppSync can connect to [Aurora Serverless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-rds-resolvers.html) clusters. First, make sure that your Aurora cluster has an `engine-mode` of `serverless`. You can verify this via the CLI by using `aws rds describe-db-clusters`.

Once you've got a cluster that is serverless, [enable the Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html) for that cluster, which will allow queries via HTTP.

Keep in mind that as of now these features are in beta and not recommended for production usage.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks. I used serverless Aurora and it worked. However, I am still getting the error, even though the data actually got inserted into the database. I'm guessing the problem is with response mapping of my schema.

Comment: Thanks, please [vote and accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it was helpful. What error are you getting now? Post a new question and link it here and I'll try to help with that too.

Comment: I tried voting, I don't have enough points for my vote to have an effect. But I have accepted the answer

Comment: I finally up-voted your answer. 